How can I get sound in my wireless bluetooth headphone?
How can I get sound in my wireless blue tooth headphone ?
This is what I have so far.
Connection failed br-connection-cancelled.




Why am I getting no responses?

Which version of Ubuntu? Did you try forgetting the device and re-adding it? Does the device work with other computers?

I was able to pair my bluetooth dongle with my cell phone. I then connected a cable and transferred the songs to my cell phone. I then installed an app on my phone that plays music.

Is your bluetooth headset working with your cellphone or another device? We need to determine if this is a hardware issue or a Ubuntu issue

@Archisman Panigrahi Yes, my headset works with my cell phone.
